# WINAPI magnification.h functions not defined in MinGW?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, magnification-api

I'm trying to compile the [MagnifierSample.cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Magnification/cpp/Windowed/MagnifierSample.cpp) from the Microsoft github with GCC (13.2.0) (MinGW w64).

Here are the includes and the WinMain() function that uses the Magnification API

```
// Ensure that the following definition is in effect before winuser.h is included.
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501    
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <magnification.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
                     _In_ LPSTR     /*lpCmdLine*/,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    if (FALSE == MagInitialize())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (FALSE == SetupMagnifier(hInstance))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwndHost, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwndHost);

    // Create a timer to update the control.
    UINT_PTR timerId = SetTimer(hwndHost, 0, timerInterval, UpdateMagWindow);

    // Main message loop.
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Shut down.
    KillTimer(NULL, timerId);
    MagUninitialize();
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

I get all these errors:

```
magnifiersample.cpp:82:18: error: 'MagInitialize' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'OleInitialize'?
magnifiersample.cpp:107:5: error: 'MagUninitialize' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'OleUninitialize'?
magnifiersample.cpp:210:28: error: 'WC_MAGNIFIER' was not declared in this scope
magnifiersample.cpp:211:20: error: 'MS_SHOWMAGNIFIEDCURSOR' was not declared in this scope
magnifiersample.cpp:225:16: error: 'MagSetWindowTransform' was not declared in this scope
magnifiersample.cpp:238:15: error: 'MagSetColorEffect' was not declared in this scope
magnifiersample.cpp:283:5: error: 'MagSetWindowSource' was not declared in this scope
```

It doesn't complains about finding the magnification.h file.

Edit:
I looked at the magnification.h file from MinGW and it does not have function declarations for the functions in the Microsoft magnification API:

```
/**
 * This file has no copyright assigned and is placed in the Public Domain.
 * This file is part of the mingw-w64 runtime package.
 * No warranty is given; refer to the file DISCLAIMER.PD within this package.
 */

#ifndef _INC_MAGNIFIER
#define _INC_MAGNIFIER

#include <winapifamily.h>

#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)

#include <wincodec.h>

#define MW_FILTERMODE_EXCLUDE 0
#define MW_FILTERMODE_INCLUDE 1

typedef struct tagMAGTRANSFORM {
    float v[3][3];
} MAGTRANSFORM, *PMAGTRANSFORM;

typedef struct tagMAGIMAGEHEADER {
    UINT width;
    UINT height;
    WICPixelFormatGUID format;
    UINT stride;
    UINT offset;
    SIZE_T cbSize;
} MAGIMAGEHEADER, *PMAGIMAGEHEADER;

typedef struct tagMAGCOLOREFFECT {
    float transform[5][5];
} MAGCOLOREFFECT, *PMAGCOLOREFFECT;

#endif
#endif
```

Why is this? What should / can I do to use this API with MinGW?

Comment: Which GCC distro are you using?  [MinGW-w64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64)?

Comment: @genpfault: yes, i've just tried with the last one from https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries

Comment: I just tested the sample with MinGW 13 ucrt from msys2 and reproduce the same errors.

Comment: I just looked and the `magnification.h` file in msys2 at `C:\msys64\usr\include\w32api\magnification.h` is different from the one in the Windows SDK and is missing the function declarations for the magnification api.

Comment: @drescherjm: so it is a compiler problem/bug?

Comment: I think it's just an unimplemented feature in the winapi headers provided by MinGW but I may be wrong.